# How to list the SQL Server Instances installed on a local machine? ( Only local )

Tags: c#, sql-server

I would like to know if there's a way to list the SQL Server instances installed on the local computer.

`SqlDataSourceEnumerator` and `EnumAvailableSqlServers` don't do the trick as I don't need the instances that are over the local network.

Comment: See my answer - `EnumAvailableSqlServers` has a flag `localOnly` which you can set to `true` to find only SQL Server instances on your local machine

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could call EnumAvailableSQlServers with a `localOnly = True`

```
public static DataTable EnumAvailableSqlServers(bool localOnly)
```

See [MSDN docs for EnumAvailableSqlServers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms210334.aspx)

Comment: This returns 0 servers for me, but I know I have 3 instances running on my computer

Comment: If there is just one instance, it doesn't show the instance name.
In my case I've got just one (local)\SQLEXPRESS instance, but this function returns correct PC name, but empty instance name.

Comment: This doesn't work for SQL Server > 2008. Use the answer below this one if you have a newer version of SQL Server.

Answer (score 23):

Direct access to Windows Registry isn't the recommended solution by MS, because they can change keys/paths. But I agree that *SmoApplication.EnumAvailableSqlServers()* and *SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance* fails providing instances on 64-bit platforms.

Getting data from Windows Registry, keep in mind the difference in Registry access between *x86* and *x64* platforms. 64-bit edition of Windows stores data in different parts of system registry and combines them into views. So using *RegistryView* is essential.

```
using Microsoft.Win32;

RegistryView registryView = Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem ? RegistryView.Registry64 : RegistryView.Registry32;
using (RegistryKey hklm = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, registryView))
{
    RegistryKey instanceKey = hklm.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL", false);
    if (instanceKey != null)
    {
        foreach (var instanceName in instanceKey.GetValueNames())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Environment.MachineName + @"\" + instanceName);
        }
    }
}
```

If you are looking for 32-bit instances on a 64-bit OS (pretty weird, but possible), you will need to look:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server
```

Comment: That worked for me, after digging almost 3 hours.. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

```
SqlDataSourceEnumerator instance = SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance;
System.Data.DataTable table = instance.GetDataSources();
foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            if (row["ServerName"] != DBNull.Value && Environment.MachineName.Equals(row["ServerName"].ToString()))
            {
                string item = string.Empty;
                item = row["ServerName"].ToString();
                if(row["InstanceName"] != DBNull.Value ||  !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(row["InstanceName"]).Trim()))
                {
                    item += @"\" + Convert.ToString(row["InstanceName"]).Trim();
                }
                listview1.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use registry to get sql server instance name in local system

```
private void LoadRegKey()        
{            
    RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names");            
    foreach (string sk in key.GetSubKeyNames())            
    {                
      RegistryKey rkey = key.OpenSubKey(sk);                
      foreach (string s in rkey.GetValueNames())                
      {                    
         MessageBox.Show("Sql instance name:"+s);                
      }            
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Combined several methods:

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Wmi;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace SqlServerEnumerator
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dictionary<string, Func<List<string>>> methods = new Dictionary<string, Func<List<string>>>
            {
                {"CallSqlBrowser", GetLocalSqlServerInstancesByCallingSqlBrowser},
                {"CallSqlWmi32", GetLocalSqlServerInstancesByCallingSqlWmi32},
                {"CallSqlWmi64", GetLocalSqlServerInstancesByCallingSqlWmi64},
                {"ReadRegInstalledInstances", GetLocalSqlServerInstancesByReadingRegInstalledInstances},
                {"ReadRegInstanceNames", GetLocalSqlServerInstancesByReadingRegInstanceNames},
                {"CallSqlCmd", GetLocalSqlServerInstancesByCallingSqlCmd},
            };

            Dictionary<string, List<string>> dictionary = methods
                .AsParallel()
                .ToDictionary(v => v.Key, v => v.Value().OrderBy(n => n, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase).ToList());

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> pair in dictionary)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("~~{0}~~", pair.Key));
                pair.Value.ForEach(v => Console.WriteLine(" " + v));
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static List<string> GetLocalSqlServerInstancesByCallingSqlBrowser()
        {
            DataTable dt = SmoApplication.EnumAvailableSqlServers(true);
            return dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
                .Select(v => v.Field<string>("Name"))
                .ToList();
        }

        private static List<string> GetLocalSqlServerInstancesByCallingSqlWmi32()
        {
            return LocalSqlServerInstancesByCallingSqlWmi(ProviderArchitecture.Use32bit);
        }

        private static List<string> GetLocalSqlServerInstancesByCallingSqlWmi64()
        {
            return LocalSqlServerInstancesByCallingSqlWmi(ProviderArchitecture.Use64bit);
        }

        private static List<string> LocalSqlServerInstancesByCallingSqlWmi(ProviderArchitecture providerArchitecture)
        {
            try
            {
                ManagedComputer managedComputer32 = new ManagedComputer();
                managedComputer32.ConnectionSettings.ProviderArchitecture = providerArchitecture;

                const string defaultSqlInstanceName = "MSSQLSERVER";
                return managedComputer32.ServerInstances.Cast<ServerInstance>()
                    .Select(v =>
                        (string.IsNullOrEmpty(v.Name) || string.Equals(v.Name, defaultSqlInstanceName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) ?
                            v.Parent.Name : string.Format("{0}\\{1}", v.Parent.Name, v.Name))
                    .OrderBy(v => v, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                    .ToList();
            }
            catch (SmoException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                return new List<string>();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
                return new List<string>();
            }
        }

        private static List<string> GetLocalSqlServerInstancesByReadingRegInstalledInstances()
        {
            try
            {
                // HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\InstalledInstances
                string[] instances = null;
                using (RegistryKey rk = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server"))
                {
                    if (rk != null)
                    {
                        instances = (string[])rk.GetValue("InstalledInstances");
                    }

                    instances = instances ?? new string[] { };
                }

                return GetLocalSqlServerInstances(instances);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
                return new List<string>();
            }
        }

        private static List<string> GetLocalSqlServerInstancesByReadingRegInstanceNames()
        {
            try
            {
                // HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL
                string[] instances = null;
                using (RegistryKey rk = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL"))
                {
                    if (rk != null)
                    {
                        instances = rk.GetValueNames();
                    }

                    instances = instances ?? new string[] { };
                }

                return GetLocalSqlServerInstances(instances);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
                return new List<string>();
            }
        }

        private static List<string> GetLocalSqlServerInstances(string[] instanceNames)
        {
            string machineName = Environment.MachineName;

            const string defaultSqlInstanceName = "MSSQLSERVER";
            return instanceNames
                .Select(v =>
                    (string.IsNullOrEmpty(v) || string.Equals(v, defaultSqlInstanceName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) ?
                        machineName : string.Format("{0}\\{1}", machineName, v))
                .ToList();
        }

        private static List<string> GetLocalSqlServerInstancesByCallingSqlCmd()
        {
            try
            {
                // SQLCMD -L
                int exitCode;
                string output;
                CaptureConsoleAppOutput("SQLCMD.exe", "-L", 200, out exitCode, out output);

                if (exitCode == 0)
                {
                    string machineName = Environment.MachineName;

                    return output.Split(new[] { "\r\n", "\r", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                        .Select(v => v.Trim())
                        .Where(v => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(v))
                        .Where(v => string.Equals(v, "(local)", StringComparison.Ordinal) || v.StartsWith(machineName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                        .Select(v => string.Equals(v, "(local)", StringComparison.Ordinal) ? machineName : v)
                        .Distinct(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                        .ToList();
                }

                return new List<string>();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
                return new List<string>();
            }
        }

        private static void CaptureConsoleAppOutput(string exeName, string arguments, int timeoutMilliseconds, out int exitCode, out string output)
        {
            using (Process process = new Process())
            {
                process.StartInfo.FileName = exeName;
                process.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
                process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                process.Start();

                output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

                bool exited = process.WaitForExit(timeoutMilliseconds);
                if (exited)
                {
                    exitCode = process.ExitCode;
                }
                else
                {
                    exitCode = -1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static string SetServer()
    {
        string serverName = @".\SQLEXPRESS";
        var serverNameList = SqlHelper.ListLocalSqlInstances();
        if (serverNameList != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in serverNameList)
                serverName = @"" + item;
        }
        return serverName;
    }
```

> To get local server names