# Version information not returned in SQL Server enumeration

Tags: c#, sql-server, smo

As part of an installation, I need to be able to identify the instances and versions of SQL Server installed on a machine.

I am using [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms210425.aspx) [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301021/how-to-list-the-sql-server-instances-installed-on-a-local-machine-only-local/5301137#5301137) to get a list of the instances of SQL server on the local machine; I'm only interested in the local machine.

I need to get all instances, and check the versions. We need SQL Server 2008 R2 for the application.

However, what I get back is:

```
"MACHINENAME"
"MACHINENAME"
{}
true
{} (**)
true
```

whereas I was expecting (**) to have the version in it.

I see that this technique fails if there is a firewall in place:

*This method fails to list the local instance if a firewall is operating on the server. The
firewall blocks any broadcast traffic issued when the method is called, even if the sender
is from local machine.*

but I get the same result, regardless of enabling or disabling the firewall.

Are there any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know, but after you get the list of servers back just query them.  You can either use a SqlCommand to send a "select @@version" query, or you could use the Server class in the Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo namespace to get this information.

Comment: And yes, I know it would be nice to not have to do an extra step and it just seems wrong :)  But it will be more reliable since you can rest assured you won't get "**" back from either of these options.