# How to find first instance of SQL Server in the System and fill it in the TextBox of Windows Forms Application?

Tags: sql-server, winforms

I'd like to know how to find first instance of SQL Server in the System and fill it in the TextBox of Windows Forms Application?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6824188/sqldatasourceenumerator-instance-getdatasources-does-not-locate-local-sql-serv look at this...

Comment: You can use this [how-to-list-the-sql-server-instances](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301021/how-to-list-the-sql-server-instances-installed-on-a-local-machine-only-local) or [PowerShell instances](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2013/find-sql-server-instances-across-your-network-using-windows-powershell/)